# Duration of Text on Canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas

Is it possible to set the Duration of Text on a canvas?

I have a game and when the player reaches a new HighScore i want to display "NEW HighScore" and then make it disappear after 2 seconds.

I tried something like setDuration but it does not work.

Comment: Simply use a CountDownTimer and delete the text after 2 secs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a CountDownTimer and reset the text after 2 seconds.

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        mTextField.setText("");
    }

};

if(score > highscore){
highscore = score;
mTextField.setText("New HighScore");
timer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

you could actually achieve this, but I'm fairly sure you don't want the behaviour resulting from this, as this will block your UI for 2 seconds.

However, you can try to execute it in a thread, or, as others already answered, use a CountDownTimer